# WPF - Commands and referencing objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have got C# 5.0 All-In-One for Dummies, but it doesn't really show a good example for what I want to achieve. Here is my XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Images/039.JPG" x:Name="example_image"/>
        <Image Source="Images/example.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Panel.ZIndex="999" x:Name="example_logo"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Slider Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Maximum="100" SmallChange="1" ToolTip="Watermark size in percent (%)" Value="{Binding Path=SliderValue, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=SliderValue, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

So I have got 2 images, one image 1 (the watermark) on top of the other image 2. And I have got a slider, which I have Binded to a value in my App.xaml.cs.

What I need to do is code a custom command, which will fire when the slider is moved, I need to add some parameters to this command which will be the 2 images names, so I can manipulate these controls using the command.

I can't seem to workout how I would do this, I have made a separate file for my commands called Commands.cs.

Why do I want to send the 2 images names as parameters, well so the command is reusable, if I want to use a different image control.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a Command property on the Slider although it's possible to add one (see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4326429)

A simple option would be to handle the `ValueChanged` event on the Slider or perhaps if the `SliderValue` property on App.xaml.cs is a then you could fire your reusable "command" code from its setter.

Side note, you may want to look into the MVVM pattern rather than putting all your code in the code behind.

Comment: I am attempting to use a MVVM pattern, as I thought by separating my commands into Commands.cs is separating the user input from the code behind. #

Comment: Ive not yet added the command property by the way, as im just trying to get some clarification on how it works :D

Comment: SliderValue should probably be in your VM rather than in app.xaml.cs then, you can then call your command code from the setter.